# Markov and Chebyshev inequalities for Poisson and Binomial random variables.

Tags: probability

$X\ \tilde\ {}\ Binom(2n, 1/2),\ \ \ \  Y\ \tilde{}\ Poiss(n)$ and $X,Y$ are independent.  Let $Z=X+Y$.  Find estimation (using Markov's and Chebyshev's inequality) on $P(Z\ge 3n)$.

**My attempts**
*Markov:*
$P(Z\ge 3n) = P(X+Y\ge 3n) \le \frac{EX+EY}{3n}=\frac{1/2n+n}{3n}=\frac{3/2}{3}=\frac12$
*Chebyshev:*
$P(Z\ge 3n) = P(X+Y\ge 3n) \le \frac{Var X+Var Y}{3n} = \frac{1/4n+n}{n} = 5/12$

Am I ok ?

Comment: not $5/12$ but $5/4$.

Comment: Markov is ok ?   Chebyshev (with your corection) is ok ?

Comment: Markov is not OK (see solution by @NP-hard). Neither Chebyshev because $P(Z\ge 3n)$ cannot directly be given by Chebyshev which deals with expressions $P(|Z-m|\ge a)$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = 2n \cdot \frac{1}{2} = n
$$
Therefore, by Markov inequality,
$$
\Pr[Z \geq 3n] \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[Z]}{3n} = \frac{n + n}{3n} = \frac{2}{3}
$$
By one-sided Chebyshev's inequality,
$$
\Pr[Z \geq 3n] = \Pr[Z \geq \mathbb{E}[Z] + n] \leq \frac{Var[Z]}{Var[Z] + n^2} = \frac{\frac{3}{2}n}{\frac{3}{2}n + n^2}
$$

Comment: Why $\le \frac{Var [Z]}{Var[Z]+n^2}$ ? For me it should be $\frac{Var[Z]}{n^2}$

Comment: @HaskellFun The standard Chebyshev's inequality has the form $$\Pr[|X - \mathbb{E}[X]| > t] \leq \frac{Var[X]}{t^2}$$ But we wanna know $$\Pr[X - \mathbb{E}[X] > t]$$ here, so instead the one-sided Chebyshev's inequality (without absolute value) is used.

Comment: @HaskellFun You can still use the looser bound $\frac{Var[Z]}{n^2}$ in your question because $$\Pr[Z - \mathbb{E}[Z] \geq n] \leq \Pr[|Z - \mathbb{E}[Z]| \geq n]$$

Comment: Ok, it is ok also to do:  $\Pr[Z - \mathbb{E}[Z] \geq n] \leq \Pr[|Z - \mathbb{E}[Z]| \geq n]\le \frac{3/2n}{n^2}$ ?

Comment: @HaskellFun Looks good to me.